# Cómo puedo hacer fk y tabla intermedia n:m

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

¿Cómo puedo arreglar el error en la tabla compra_proveedor y en la tabla metodo_de pago?

Error 1005 "foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Como puedo hacer que las fk funcionen en el script ?! 
Como se realiza una tabla n:m en este caso la tabla intermedia compra_proveedor

```
create database if not exists ARTE;

use ARTE;



CREATE TABLE USUARIO (
  id_cliente INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombre text  (40),
  apellido text   (40),
  correo text   (40) ,
  telefono  int   (12) ,

 primary key (id_cliente)

 )engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE  DOMICILIO (
  id_domicilio  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  calle_b text (30),
  Numero_b int (10),
  Fraccioneamiento_b text (40),
  CodigoPostal_b int (10) ,
  Estado_b text (40),
  Ciudad_b text (40),
  Pais_b text  (40) ,
  id_cliente INT NOT NULL ,

primary key (id_domicilio),
constraint id_cliente foreign key (id_cliente) references USUARIO (id_cliente)
 )engine=InnoDB;






  CREATE TABLE PROVEEDOR  (
  id_proveedor  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  existencia_d int(255),
  NomnbreDeLaEtnia_d text (40),
  NombreDelArtesno_d text (40),


primary key (id_proveedor)

 )engine=InnoDB;



  CREATE TABLE METODO_DE_PAGO (

  id_MetPag  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tarjeta_e int  (100),


primary key (id_MetPag)


 )engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE ORDEN (

  id_orden   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cantidad_d int  (255),
  precio_d int (255),
  moneda text (10),
  fecha datetime,

  primary key (id_orden)

 );


  CREATE TABLE COMPRA_PROVEEDOR (

  id_proveedor1 INT NOT NULL ,  
  id_proveedor INT NOT NULL,
  id_art INT NOT NULL,

   primary key ( id_proveedor1),

 constraint id_proveedor
 foreign key (id_proveedor)
 references PROVEEDOR (id_proveedor),
 Constraint id_art
 foreign key (id_art)
 references  ARTICULO (id_art)

ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 )engine=InnoDB;


   CREATE TABLE ARTICULO  (
  id_art INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  NombreArticulo_c text (40),
  Precio_c int (40),
  moneda_c text (40),
  existencia_c int,
  fecha_c datetime,
  id_orden INT NOT NULL,

primary key (id_art),
constraint id_orden foreign key (id_orden) references ORDEN (id_orden)

 )engine=InnoDB;

 CREATE TABLE COMPRA (
  id_compra  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_cliente INT NOT NULL ,
  id_domicilio INT NOT NULL ,
  id_orden INT NOT NULL ,

primary key (id_compra),
constraint id_cliente  foreign key (id_cliente) references USUARIO (id_cliente),
constraint id_domicilio foreign key (id_domicilio) references DOMICILIO (id_domicilio),
constraint id_orden foreign key (id_orden) references ORDEN  (id_orden),
constraint id_MetPag foreign key (id_MetPag) references METODO_DE_PAGO   (id_MetPag)

 ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
  )
```

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías aclarar exactamente cuál es el problema? ¿Qué error te marca y dónde? Saludos

Comment: no corren las ultimas tablas por error 1005

Comment: No debiste eliminar la DDL que tenías antes. Debiste agregar la info necesaria. Y por favor no escribas todo en mayúsculas, es innecesario, no hará más visible tu publicación, y en el contexto web parece que estuvieras gritando. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Habías creado una tabla dependiente antes que la referenciada, de ahí el error. Te adjunto un script libre de errores de sintaxis que genera el diagrama de la figura:

[image: Diagrama de la base de datos]

```
CREATE DATABASE if NOT EXISTS stack_arte;
USE stack_arte;

CREATE TABLE USUARIO (
 id_cliente INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 nombre varchar(40),
 apellido varchar(40),
 correo varchar(40),
 telefono int(12),
 primary key (id_cliente)
)engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE DOMICILIO (
 id_domicilio INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 calle_b varchar(30),
 Numero_b int(10),
 Fraccioneamiento_b varchar(40),
 CodigoPostal_b int(10),
 Estado_b varchar(40),
 Ciudad_b varchar(40),
 Pais_b varchar(40),
 id_cliente INT NOT NULL,
 primary key (id_domicilio),
 constraint id_cliente foreign key (id_cliente) references USUARIO (id_cliente)
)engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE PROVEEDOR (
 id_proveedor INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 existencia_d int(255),
 NomnbreDeLaEtnia_d varchar(40),
 NombreDelArtesno_d varchar(40),
 primary key (id_proveedor)
)engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE METODO_DE_PAGO (
 id_MetPag INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 tarjeta_e int(100),
 primary key (id_MetPag)
)engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE ORDEN (
 id_orden INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 cantidad_d int(255),
 precio_d int(255),
 moneda varchar(10),
 fecha datetime,
 primary key (id_orden)
);

CREATE TABLE ARTICULO (
 id_art INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 NombreArticulo_c varchar(40),
 Precio_c int(40),
 moneda_c varchar(40),
 existencia_c int,
 fecha_c datetime,
 id_orden INT NOT NULL,
 primary key (id_art),
 constraint id_orden foreign key (id_orden) references ORDEN (id_orden)
)engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE COMPRA_PROVEEDOR(
 id_proveedor1 INT NOT NULL, 
 id_proveedor INT NOT NULL,
 id_art INT NOT NULL,
 primary key (id_proveedor1),
 constraint id_proveedor foreign key(id_proveedor) references PROVEEDOR(id_proveedor),
 Constraint id_art foreign key (id_art) references ARTICULO (id_art)
 ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE COMPRA (
 id_compra INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 id_cliente INT NOT NULL,
 id_domicilio INT NOT NULL,
 id_orden INT NOT NULL,
 id_MetPag int NOT NULL,
 primary key (id_compra),
 foreign key (id_cliente) references USUARIO (id_cliente),
 foreign key (id_domicilio) references DOMICILIO (id_domicilio),
 foreign key (id_orden) references ORDEN (id_orden),
 foreign key (id_MetPag) references METODO_DE_PAGO (id_MetPag)
 ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Con respecto a la tabla `compra_proveedor`, yo habría hecho algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE COMPRA_PROVEEDOR(
 id_compra_proveedor INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
 id_proveedor INT NOT NULL,
 id_art INT NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE(id_proveedor,id_art),
 foreign key(id_proveedor) references PROVEEDOR(id_proveedor),
 foreign key (id_art) references ARTICULO (id_art)
 ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)engine=InnoDB;
```

La clave única es para evitar vincular el mismo artículo al mismo proveedor más de una vez, pues entiendo que es el objetivo de esa tabla.